# chirpsdk after 3.4.6 result in ImportError: cannot import name 'ChirpConnect' from 'chirpsdk'

Tags: python-3.x, chirp

I am working on a project including Chirp and chirpsdk.
Recently I moved from Raspbian Stretch to Raspbian Buster and updated many parts of the software including chirpsdk (from 3.4.6 to 3.5).
This resulted in my reworked, tiny, chirpsdk-example-python script is not being able to run.

It stops on the following line:
`from chirpsdk import ChirpConnect, CallbackSet, ConnectError`

with the following message:
ImportError: cannot import name 'ChirpConnect' from 'chirpsdk'

I tried to understand what was going wrong by removing the reference to ChirpConnect.
This resulted in the error pointing to ConnectError.
Removing ConnectError too gave no further error messages, so CallbackSet was obviously found in chirpsdk.

After some further troubleshooting, I can get back to a working envrionment after uninstalling chirpsdk 3.5 and installing 3.4.6 again.

Spent some time searching for changelogs etc without being able to find something useful.

Can somebody tell me what I need to do in order to get this running with chirpsdk 3.5?
I am using Python 3.7.3 and my python-coding skills are below zero.

/Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chirp have renamed all of the functions and classnames to refer to ChirpSDK instead of ChirpConnect in the latest release. Please follow the latest documentation for a full set of changes - https://developers.chirp.io/docs/getting-started/python

You can read more about the changes in this blog post - https://blog.chirp.io/chirpsdk-update-sep19/

Comment: Thanks! Always reading in the wrong (odd) places and never looking at the obvious ones.